# Crash on iOS 16 physical device : Warning: observer object was not disposed manually with Dispose()

Tags: ios, xamarin, observable, maui

I have a method for fetching images from the gallery on iOS in NET MAUI. I execute it everytime on the OnAppearing method in the page. But whenever I minimize the applicaiton and return to it, thus triggering the OnAppearing method the app is terminated and I am faced with the error : 2022-11-22 13:58:31.287 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[1018:30754] Warning: observer object was not disposed manually with Dispose()
I am trying to add the photos to an observable collection and display them on the Page, oddly on Android is working but the implementation there is different. Any help or pointers are appreciated. I am testing it on a physical iphone 8 device running ios 16 using hot restart.

```
[RelayCommand]
        public async void LoadNewPictures()
        {
            List<MediaAsset> mediaAssets = new List<MediaAsset>();
            var fetch = await mediaService.RetrieveMediaAssetsAsync();
            

        }
```

```
 public class MediaService
    {

        bool requestStop = false;

        bool _isLoading = false;
        public bool IsLoading => _isLoading;

        public event EventHandler<MediaEventArgs> OnMediaAssetLoaded;
#if IOS

        public async Task<bool> RequestPermissionAsync()
        {
            var status = PHPhotoLibrary.AuthorizationStatus;

            bool authotization = status == PHAuthorizationStatus.Authorized;

            if (!authotization)
            {
                authotization = await PHPhotoLibrary.RequestAuthorizationAsync() == PHAuthorizationStatus.Authorized;
            }
            return authotization;

        }

#endif
        public async Task<IList<MediaAsset>> RetrieveMediaAssetsAsync(CancellationToken? cancelToken = null)
        {
#if IOS
            requestStop = false;

            if (!cancelToken.HasValue)
                cancelToken = CancellationToken.None;

            // We create a TaskCompletionSource of decimal
            var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<IList<MediaAsset>>();

            // Registering a lambda into the cancellationToken
            cancelToken.Value.Register(() =>
            {
                requestStop = true;
                taskCompletionSource.TrySetCanceled();
            });

            _isLoading = true;

            var task = LoadMediaAsync();

            // Wait for the first task to finish among the two
            var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, taskCompletionSource.Task);
            _isLoading = false;

            return await completedTask;
        }
        async Task<IList<MediaAsset>> LoadMediaAsync()
        {
            IList<MediaAsset> assets = new List<MediaAsset>();
            var imageManager = new PHCachingImageManager();
            var hasPermission = await RequestPermissionAsync();
            if (hasPermission)
            {
                await Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    var thumbnailRequestOptions = new PHImageRequestOptions();
                    thumbnailRequestOptions.ResizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeMode.Fast;
                    thumbnailRequestOptions.DeliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.FastFormat;
                    thumbnailRequestOptions.NetworkAccessAllowed = true;
                    thumbnailRequestOptions.Synchronous = true;

                    var requestOptions = new PHImageRequestOptions();
                    requestOptions.ResizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeMode.Exact;
                    requestOptions.DeliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.HighQualityFormat;
                    requestOptions.NetworkAccessAllowed = true;
                    requestOptions.Synchronous = true;

                    var fetchOptions = new PHFetchOptions();
                    fetchOptions.SortDescriptors = new NSSortDescriptor[] { new NSSortDescriptor("creationDate", false) };
                    fetchOptions.Predicate = NSPredicate.FromFormat($"mediaType == {(int)PHAssetMediaType.Image} || mediaType == {(int)PHAssetMediaType.Video}");
                    var fetchResults = PHAsset.FetchAssets(fetchOptions);
                    var tmpPath = Path.GetTempPath();
                    var allAssets = fetchResults.Select(p => p as PHAsset).ToArray();
                    var thumbnailSize = new CGSize(300.0f, 300.0f);

                    imageManager.StartCaching(allAssets, thumbnailSize, PHImageContentMode.AspectFit, thumbnailRequestOptions);
                    imageManager.StartCaching(allAssets, PHImageManager.MaximumSize, PHImageContentMode.AspectFit, requestOptions);


                    foreach (var result in fetchResults)
                    {
                        var phAsset = (result as PHAsset);
                        var name = PHAssetResource.GetAssetResources(phAsset)?.FirstOrDefault()?.OriginalFilename;
                        var asset = new MediaAsset()
                        {
                            Id = phAsset.LocalIdentifier,
                            Name = name,
                            Type = phAsset.MediaType == PHAssetMediaType.Image ? MediaAssetType.Image : MediaAssetType.Video,
                            Creation = (DateTime)phAsset.CreationDate,
                        };

                        imageManager.RequestImageForAsset(phAsset, thumbnailSize, PHImageContentMode.AspectFit, thumbnailRequestOptions, (image, info) =>
                        {

                            if (image != null)
                            {
                                NSData imageData = null;
                                if (image.CGImage.RenderingIntent == CGColorRenderingIntent.Default)
                                {
                                    imageData = image.AsJPEG(0.8f);

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    imageData = image.AsPNG();
                                }

                                if (imageData != null)
                                {

                                    var fileName = Path.Combine(tmpPath, $"tmp_thumbnail_{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name)}.jpg");
                                    NSError error = null;
                                    imageData.Save(fileName, true, out error);
                                    if (error == null)
                                    {


                                        asset.PreviewPath = fileName;

                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        });
                        switch (phAsset.MediaType)
                        {

                            case PHAssetMediaType.Image:

                                imageManager.RequestImageForAsset(phAsset, PHImageManager.MaximumSize, PHImageContentMode.AspectFit, requestOptions, (image, info) =>
                                {

                                    if (image != null)
                                    {
                                        NSData imageData = null;
                                        if (image.CGImage.RenderingIntent == CGColorRenderingIntent.Default)
                                        {
                                            imageData = image.AsJPEG(0.8f);

                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            imageData = image.AsPNG();
                                        }

                                        if (imageData != null)
                                        {
                                            var fileName = Path.Combine(tmpPath, $"tmp_{name}");
                                            NSError error = null;
                                            imageData.Save(fileName, true, out error);
                                            if (error == null)
                                            {
                                                asset.Path = fileName;
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                break;
                            case PHAssetMediaType.Video:
                                var videoRequestOptions = new PHVideoRequestOptions();
                                videoRequestOptions.NetworkAccessAllowed = true;
                                var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                                imageManager.RequestAVAsset(phAsset, null, (vAsset, audioMix, info) =>
                                {
                                    var avAsset = vAsset as AVUrlAsset;
                                    var avData = NSData.FromUrl(avAsset.Url);
                                    NSError error = null;
                                    var path = Path.Combine(tmpPath, $"tmp_{name}");
                                    avData.Save(path, true, out error);
                                    if (error == null)
                                    {
                                        asset.Path = path;


                                        tcs.TrySetResult(true);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        tcs.TrySetResult(false);
                                    }
                                });
                                await tcs.Task;
                                break;
                        }

                        UIApplication.SharedApplication.InvokeOnMainThread(delegate
                        {
                            OnMediaAssetLoaded?.Invoke(this, new MediaEventArgs(asset));
                        });
                        assets.Add(asset);

                        if (requestStop)
                            break;
                    }
                });

                imageManager.StopCaching();
            }
            return assets;
#else
            List<MediaAsset> mediaAssets = new List<MediaAsset>();
            return mediaAssets;
#endif

        }



    }
```

```
<ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                EventName="Appearing"
                Command="{Binding LoadNewPicturesCommand }" />
        <toolkit:AnimationBehavior
            EventName="Disappearing"
            Command="{Binding DisatachCommand}"/>
    </ContentPage.Behaviors>
```

Comment: what line causes the crash?  Have you tried adding any exception handling to your code?

Comment: It is hard telling but essentially if I have more than 20 photos in the Photos Gallery it crashes, but before that it doesnt, another thing is that since I am using #if IOS I cant really see what happens to certain object because its native ios code and I have wrapped it into these statements in order to use it in a service I register in the viewmodel, but I will try to pinpoint more precisely

Comment: I also tried implementing a using statement wiht the imageManager since its an IDisposable but it crashes the app once again, now I am going to try goin line by line

Comment: Can you try adding breakpoints to find out exactly where it crashes?